# How do I tell pip to just skip over any failed installation while installing a package that depends on them?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install a package using pip.  However, when pip is installing said package, it keeps failing on another package package that I don't even really need.  I was wondering if there was any simple way to tell pip to just skip over that package when it gets to it.

To be more specific, I am trying to install dwave-ocean-sdk, with

```
         pip installl dwave-ocean-sdk
```

everything starts out good, put then pip gets to installing another package called dwave-neal where it fails to build the wheel. I dont need this package, and I want pip to just skip over it.  I would really appreciate it if someone could show me how to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pip install --no-deps dwave-ocean-sdk` and then install the dependencies that you actually want.